# SQLiteException: unable to open database file emerges on some phones

Tags: android, sqlite

I have published an app on the market. I got a comment that it doesn't go on SG3. One my of friends told me that it doesn't go on her phone. He has SG1 (2.3.3), so maybe its a galaxy specific problem (it works on Galaxy S). She sent me the stacktrace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.b2creative.b2callstats/com.b2creative.b2callstats.Calllogs}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:630)
>   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
>   at com.b2creative.b2callstats.HotOrNot.open(HotOrNot.java:69) at
>   com.b2creative.b2callstats.Calllogs.refreshList(Calllogs.java:1579) at
>   com.b2creative.b2callstats.Calllogs.onCreate(Calllogs.java:277) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   ... 11 more

While googling, I have found several similar errors, but I couldn't find out what can be the cause of this problem and it is really hard to test, since it doesn't emerge on my phone, or the ZTE Blade and a Samsung galaxy mini that I have at home.

I wanted to check the database path on her phone but since it force closes at the start, I couldn't get it. On my phone it is tha default path:/data/data/com.b2creative.b2callstats/databases/CallDatabase.

Maybe there is no such path on her phone?

Part of my sqliteopenhelper class:

```
private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
              KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
              KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_PHONE + " VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_TYPE + " CHAR(1) NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_DURATION + " VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_DATE + " VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_CONTACTID + " VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL)"
              );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public HotOrNot(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
        }

    public HotOrNot open() throws SQLException{ 
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();    //error line 08.19.2012 6:32:57 PM
        return this;
        }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
        }
```

PS: She looks good... :)

Comment: It's not the phone's fault.  I have my app using SQLite on both SG1 and SG3 phones.  What's the value of DATABASE_NAME that is passed into the super method?

Comment: It is CallDatabase, you can see in the path, or I don't understand you

Comment: Beats me as to why it doesn't work. You might want to find a user with an S3 and run it debug. I had to do that for one of my apps, although not for this as my sqlite worked fine on both.

Comment: Anyone? I can't work this out

Comment: @erdomester were you able to fix this issue?